# Irreducible Polynomial Relation to Field Extension Degree

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I've been learning about intro Galois theory, and ran into the following statement (in the context of quadratic field extension $L/K$):

If an irreducible polynomial over $K$ of degree $n$ has a root in $L$, then $[L:K] \geq n$.

Is this true, and if so, why?

Comment: Let $a$ the root of the polynomial. Then use $K(a)\subseteq L$.

Comment: Thanks! So to confirm, is the idea that $[L : K] = [L : K(a)][K(a) : K] = [L : K(a)] * n \geq n$?

Comment: Yes, that's it.